# CPU (or Memory/etc) plugin for Munin and Mac OSX?

Tags: mac-osx, monitoring, mac, munin

I install munined on Mac OSX, however there is no CPU or Memory or very basic plugins installed. On the system `/opt/munin/lib/plugins` it has lots of advanced plugins like apache or bind9, but nothing for the basics. What could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins don't exist as Munin was developed from a Linux standpoint.

If you need the functionality, I suggest that you review how the Linux plugins for your needs work; then port them to Mac OS X.

You would want to review the man pages for:

- vm_stat
- iostat

They are *different* to what you would expect from a Unix system.

Comment: Oh brilliant! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Aqua Ray's Munin Plugins](http://armunin.aquaray.com/).

Comment: That URL is dead.